# Where is the startup (autostart) folder in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot, windows-8.1

Well, Windows 8 has no Start Menu any more and the **startup folder** has disappeared also.

Where can I find that folder? Or is there a new way with Metro?

Comment: Its still there, just not readily available...http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/where-is-startup-folder-how-to-edit-startup-items-in-windows-8/

Comment: Oh there it is - quite complicated though. But I'm not able to add new startup applications from the "Task Manager". Just view/deactivate.

Comment: Just drag your program shortcut to that folder, then it will start with windows.

Comment: yes it is. In Win 7 and before I always opened the startup folder from the start menu. This is not possible anymore, therefore a good question.

Comment: Related: *[Run a script on start up on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/954950/run-a-script-on-start-up-windows-10)*

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It can be found here:

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

or easier to access with this command in the Run <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> prompt:

```
shell:startup
```

[image]

[Here are even more explanations of how accessing/viewing the startup folder.](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/where-is-startup-folder-how-to-edit-startup-items-in-windows-8/)

Comment: `shell:startup` works in Win7, as well!

Comment: Wouldn’t it be better to use environment variables instead of a hard-coded path?

Comment: Don't understand what you mean. This has nothing to do with environment variables, this shows just the path to the startup folder.

Comment: You would actually use `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below steps to add startup programs in Windows 8:

1. Open the Run command by typing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
2. Type in the command as `%APPDATA%` then press Enter. This should take you to `C:\Users\[you]\AppData\Roaming`.
3. Go to `\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`. The full path should look like: `C:\Users\[you]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

**Note**: You can easily skip steps 2 and 3 by simply typing the command `shell:Startup` at the Run command instead of `%APPDATA%`

4. Now add any shortcut which you wanted to add in for the startup applications. You can do it by simply copying the existing shortcut and placing it here. Or **Right-click | New | Create Shortcut** and you can browse to the wanted program to add a shortcut to it here

Answer (score 0):

After forgetting the `shell:startup` command a few times (and doing a cleanup which wiped the history from the run prompt)...

1. Run `shell:startup`
2. Go up one level to `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`
3. Right-click on the `Startup` folder
4. Click 'Pin to Start'

Then it's just <kbd>Win</kbd>+'Startup' and the search should find it for you next time you forget.

Ta-da - 10 seconds saved off your life.

Answer (score 0):

The user specific startup folder can be access with `shell:startup`

The all users version can be accessed with `shell:common startup`

This can be entered in an Explorer address bar or the Run box.