# Windows 8: Startup folder?

Tags: windows-8, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the startup (autostart) folder in Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/489777/where-is-the-startup-autostart-folder-in-windows-8)

In previous versions of Windows there was a folder called "Startup" located in the Start menu where you could drag shortcuts to programs you wanted to start when Windows first boots.

Is there an equivalent to this in Windows 8?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be found on a per user basis under:

```
C:\users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

or globally under:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp
```

Comment: N.B. as in the duplicate question - the quickest is Start > Run > `shell:startup`