# How do I add a program to startup automatically in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

There are certain programs I want to have running as soon as my machine starts. Like Outlook and Skype. I don't want to have to start each one every time I power up my computer. How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a different program to startup](https://superuser.com/questions/733501/adding-a-different-program-to-startup)

Comment: has anyone ever considered amalgamating questions along with answers? it always seems to be the policy to say 'duplicate question' when the reason for the new question was that the original search produced zero results based on the forming of the question.

Answer (score 2):

- Make a copy of a shortcut to your program.

  - see: https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/make-desktop-shortcuts-windows-10
- Press the windows start button and type `Run`
- Type `shell:startup` in the Run dialog and press enter. A folder should appear
- Copy your shortcut you made above and paste it into said folder.