# Find out what is starting firefox on windows starup

Tags: windows, windows-8, cmd.exe, scheduled-tasks

Something set up firefox on windows machine to start and go to certain url as user logins into system.

In process explorer I see, that Firefox is started as "firefox.exe -osint -url "somenastything" and cmd window flashing briefly as I login. I can see pid of the parent, which is (4300) or something. I enabled event history in task scheduler, but from the logs, I don't see process with corresponding pid. How does this thing managed to auto-start then?

Comment: Use [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to figure it out?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 thank you, this answered my question

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I would like you to submit this as the answer so I could properly "close" question

Comment: Also see [Where is the startup (autostart) folder in Windows 8](http://superuser.com/questions/489777/where-is-the-startup-autostart-folder-in-windows-8)